# Centralize navbar css/html

Tags: html, css, navbar

I appreciate if you can help me with this little problem (I think), I'm just trying to make the navbar is centered, I do not know exactly how to do this since I am a novice in this area, thank you again for your attention and and everyone who can help me.

Example of how I want the navbar:

[image: Navbar]

```
<!-- ---- HTML ---- -->

<div id="menu">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Início</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Relatar erros</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Guia</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Doar </a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">Sobre</a></li>
  <li><a href="#login">Contato</a></li>
  </ul>
</ul>
</div>

<!-- ---- CSS ---- -->

#menu {
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
    margin-right: -5px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-top: -4px; }

ul {
    list-style-type: none;  margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #0F0F0F;
    margin-right: -8px;
    margin-left: -8px; }

li {
    float: left;

}

li:last-child {
    border-right: none; }

li a {
    display: block;     
    font: bold 14px Franklin Gothic Demi,Tahoma,Halvetica;
    color: red;
    border-bottom:3px solid #0c0c0c;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 3px 0;
    border-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 12px;
    text-decoration: none; }

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #000000;
    border-bottom:3px solid #ff0000;
    color: white; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;  margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #0F0F0F;
    margin-right: -8px;
    margin-left: -8px; 
    text-align: center;
    }

li {
    display: inline-block;

}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/gamge71q/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `float: left;` in your `li`.

Just use `display: inline-block;`.

```css
#menu {
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
    margin-right: -5px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-top: -4px; }

ul {
    list-style-type: none;  margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #0F0F0F;
    margin-right: -8px;
    margin-left: -8px; }

li {
    display: inline-block;

}

li:last-child {
    border-right: none; }

li a {
    display: block;     
    font: bold 14px Franklin Gothic Demi,Tahoma,Halvetica;
    color: red;
    border-bottom:3px solid #0c0c0c;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 3px 0;
    border-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 12px;
    text-decoration: none; }

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #000000;
    border-bottom:3px solid #ff0000;
    color: white; }
```

```html
<div id="menu">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Início</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Relatar erros</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Guia</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Doar </a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">Sobre</a></li>
  <li><a href="#login">Contato</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:inline-block;` instead of `float:left` and don't forget to [remove extra spaces](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) which is occurred by `display:inline-block;`.

**Why you have to remove** `float:left;`.

According to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats):

> **Floats**
>
> A float is a box that is shifted to the left or right on the current
>   line.

So `text-align:center;` doesn't have any effect on `li`s.

```css
#menu {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: -5px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: -4px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #0F0F0F;
  margin-right: -8px;
  margin-left: -8px;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Início</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#news">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Relatar erros</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Guia</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Doar </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about">Sobre</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#login">Contato</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
 #menu {
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
    margin-right: -5px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-top: -4px; }

ul {
    list-style-type: none;  
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #0F0F0F;
    margin-right: -8px;
    margin-left: -8px; 
    text-align: center;
    }

li {
    display: inline-block;

}

li:last-child {
    border-right: none; }

li a {
    display: block;     
    font: bold 14px Franklin Gothic Demi,Tahoma,Halvetica;
    color: red;
    border-bottom:3px solid #0c0c0c;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 3px 0;
    border-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 12px;
    text-decoration: none; }

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #000000;
    border-bottom:3px solid #ff0000;
    color: white; }
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/gamge71q/9/)